# How to login the page using after hashing password

Tags: php, mysql, hash, passwords

i have hashed the password when a user will register ...but when i am trying to login the page it is showing that username or password is wrong...

**Here is below the hashing code**

```
// Get values from form
$fullname=$_POST['userid'];
$username=$_POST['username'];
$email=$_POST['uemail'];
$password=$_POST['passid'];
$birthdate=$_POST['birthdate'];
$country=$_POST['mytextarea'];
$hash = hash('sha256', $password);

function createSalt()
{
    $text = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
    return substr($text, 0, 3);
}

$salt = createSalt();
$password = hash('sha256', $salt . $hash);
// Insert data into mysql
$sql="INSERT INTO tbl_registration(`fullname`,`username`,`email`,`password`,`birthdate`, `country`) VALUES('{$fullname}', '{$username}', '{$email}', '{$password}', '{$birthdate}', '{$country}' )";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

**Here is below i am using the login code...**

```
// userName and password sent from form
$myusername=$_POST['username'];
$mypassword=$_POST['password'];

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if($count==1 ){
    if(crypt($password, $row['Password']) == $row['Password'])
    {       
        header("location:index.php");
        exit();
    }
}
else {
    //echo "Wrong Username or Password";
    header("Location:login.php?errorMssg=".urlencode("Wrong Username or Password"));
}
```

So what i will do now..

Comment: When user register you encrypt the password, so in the database the encrypted value stored. When user login they type normal character ex: a2!ASdasdF. So you need to encrypt this input value before comparng the password provided from database against password from user input using same encryption method.

Comment: @Nucleo1985...what i need to change in my checklogin option...

Comment: Alright, i will give little illustration using answer.

Comment: @Nucleo1985 The password is hashed and not encrypted. Encryption is reversible while hashing is one-way.

Comment: @Gumbo, ah yes. Maybe he have to store it in 2 place, one in DB and the other in JSON maybe. So search in json array via username or email matching? he cant compare dynamically random hash vs static value inside db directly i think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are comparing the hashed/salted password with the text-password.

For example:
5a44e87906e4e5dbf7991d5784fd56f14dc426aafbd8dbb7b1e0953e1399f2ad is not equals foo

Note: mysql functions are deprecated. You should use PDO or other. You code can be written a little bit cleaner.  If you need a better explanation, I can help you with it.

edited hashing code:

```
// Get values from form
$fullname=$_POST['userid'];
$username=$_POST['username'];
$email=$_POST['uemail'];
$password=$_POST['passid'];
$birthdate=$_POST['birthdate'];
$country=$_POST['mytextarea'];
$hash = hash('sha256', $password);

function createSalt()
{
    return '2123293dsj2hu2besdbsjdsd';
}

$salt = createSalt();
$password = hash('sha256', $salt . $hash);
// Insert data into mysql
$sql="INSERT INTO tbl_registration(`fullname`,`username`,`email`,`password`,`birthdate`, `country`) VALUES('{$fullname}', '{$username}', '{$email}', '{$password}', '{$birthdate}', '{$country}' )";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

edited login code:

```
// userName and password sent from form
$myusername=$_POST['username'];
$mypassword=$_POST['password'];

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$salt = createSalt();
$hash = hash('sha256', $mypassword);
$mypassword = hash('sha256', $salt . $hash);

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if($count==1 ){
    if(crypt($password, $row['Password']) == $row['Password'])
    {       
        header("location:index.php");
        exit();
    }
}
else {
    //echo "Wrong Username or Password";
    header("Location:login.php?errorMssg=".urlencode("Wrong Username or Password"));
}

function createSalt()
{
    return '2123293dsj2hu2besdbsjdsd';
}
```

Comment: ...thank you for your answer...As per code i have hashed the password...but how to match the password at the time of login attempt ...

Comment: that is what I am saying, your original creatSalt function return random salts. You need to return a fixed one (easiest way). After you make it work correctly, I can help you with a better approach.

Comment: @Lea...when i am using createsalt() in my login page..it is showing below error msg..Call to undefined function createSalt() ...what i will do now...

Comment: @SazalAhmed, did you include at the end of the page the function?

Comment: copy and paste the function createSalt()
at the end of the login code (as I suggested it previously)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67893/discussion-between-lea-tano-and-sazal-ahmed).

Comment: A static salt is not a salt anymore, the whole purpose of the salt is, that it is different for every password. I see your effort helping to solve the problem, but this and the used SHA-256 are not safe.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some illustration, but notice this is **not a suggestion** or **good practice**.

Lets say you have database table with minimal field **Id, username, password**. So when you take the input value from password field you encrypt it using any method you choose.

Example: `$password = sha1($_POST['password']);` in this case user entering the value 'abcdef'. Because it was encrypting using sha1 you got the value turning from **abcdef** to **1f8ac10f23c5b5bc1167bda84b833e5c057a77d2**

Then you save this to database, so inside your database password column you have value **1f8ac10f23c5b5bc1167bda84b833e5c057a77d2**.

Now when the user want to login he/she entering **abcdef** <= this is what you got from the input field. So, before you compare the value from the database vs input, again you have to turn the value provided by input to **sha1** encryption.

```
$password = sha1($_POST['password'];
```

Now you got the value encrypted, so it was same type data to compare. Move forward, lets compare it.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE (username='$username' AND password='$password')";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
if (@mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1)
{
   //if one database row (record) matches the input start the session, fetch the record and insert the three values in an array
    session_start();
    $_SESSION = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    header("Location: any/where/you/like");
}
else
{
    // No match was made
    $errors[] = 'Sorry no record match with the data you have submitted';
}
```

I think thats the very basic to compare encrypted value. Once again this is **just illustration & not a solution or suggestion**.

Answer (score 0):

You should really switch to the PHP function [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php). Neither the SHA-256 algorithm and especially not a static salt are appropriate to hash passwords.

```
// Hash a new password for storing in the database.
// The function automatically generates a cryptographically safe salt.
$hashToStoreInDb = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

// Check if the hash of the entered login password, matches the stored hash.
// The salt and the cost factor will be extracted from $existingHashFromDb.
$isPasswordCorrect = password_verify($password, $existingHashFromDb);
```

If you are interested in more information, have a look at my [tutorial](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/hash/en/index.php) about safely storing passwords.

Comment: @martinstoeckli...Your article is much helpful..for understanding about safely storing passwords...Thank you very much for sharing this..